# There exists a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $|G-A|=\infty$ for each open set containing $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I happened upon an exercise in my book which tasks the reader with proving: "There exists a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $|G-A|=\infty$ for each open set containing $A$." Here the bars represent outer measure. I know that such an $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable, but I've not had much success in proving this result. This is an interesting and unexpected fact, so I'm pretty curious how one would approach this sort of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a subset of $(0,1)$ which is not (Lebesgue) measurable. Let $B$ be a measurable set (e.g. a $G_\delta$ set) such that $X\subseteq B$ and $|B|=|X|$.

**Claim 1.** $|B\setminus X|\gt0$.

**Proof.** If $|B\setminus X|=0$, then $B\setminus X$ is measurable, and so is $B\setminus(B\setminus X)=X$.

Let $\varepsilon=|B\setminus X|\gt0$.

**Claim 2.** If $G$ is measurable and $X\subseteq G$, then $|G\setminus X|\ge\varepsilon$.

**Proof.** Since $X\subseteq B\cap G\subseteq B$ we have $|X|\le|B\cap G|\le|B|=|X|$, so $|B\cap G|=|B|$ and $|B\setminus G|=|B|-|B\cap G|=0$. Since $B\setminus X\subseteq(B\setminus G)\cup(G\setminus X)$, it follows that
$$\varepsilon=|B\setminus X|\le|B\setminus G|+|G\setminus X|=0+|G\setminus X|=|G\setminus X|.$$

**Claim 3.** If $G$ is measurable and $X+n\subseteq G$, then $|G\setminus(X+n)|\ge\varepsilon$.

**Proof.** Lebesgue measure and outer measure are translation invariant. Details left to the reader.

Let $A=X+\mathbb Z=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(X+n)$.

**Claim 4.** If $G$ is measurable and $A\subseteq G$ then $|G\setminus A|=\infty$.

**Proof.**
$$|G\setminus A|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|(G\setminus A)\cap(n,n+1)|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|[G\cap(n,n+1)]\setminus(X+n)|\ge\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\varepsilon=\infty.$$

Comment: Is $A$ meant to be a proper subset of $G$ in Claim 4?

Comment: We don't have to **assume** that $A$ is a proper subset of $G$. Of course $A$ can't be equal to $G$ because $G$ is measurable and $A$ is not.

Comment: sorry if I missed something, but how does the last third line follow? You can't use countable additivity here right?

Comment: @YuiToCheng How does *what* follow? Which line are you referring to?

Comment: The last third line where you write $|G\setminus A|=\sum |(G\setminus A)\cap (n,n+1)|$

Comment: @YuiToCheng Using the OP's notation $|S|$ for the Lebesgue outer measure of a set $S$, it is indeed true that $$|S|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|S\cap(n,n+1)|$$ for an arbitrary subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A little late to the party, but up until Claim 4, we never used or implied that $G$ contains $A$, right? @bof constructed $A$ independent of this containment assumption, and if it happens that $G$ contains $A$, then Claim 4 follows. Is this correct? We assume $X \subset G$, but then (potentially) make $A$ significantly larger.

Comment: @JorgeZazueta I hardly remember this old answer, but I think you must be right, seeing as $A$ is only defined on the line just before Claim 4.

Comment: Where is the last inequality in the last line coming from? Of course, from the proof of Claim 3 we know that $|G \setminus X| = |G \setminus (X+n)|\geq \varepsilon>0$ for all $n$ (by translation invariance). But how do we know that $|(G \cap (n,n+1)) \setminus (X+n) | \geq \varepsilon$?

Comment: @RonW $X+n\subseteq A\subseteq G$ and $X+n\subseteq(0,1)+n=(n,n+1)$. Since $G\cap(n,n+1)$ is measurable and $X+n\subseteq G\cap(n,n+1)$ it follows from Claim 3 that $|[G\cap(n,n+1)]\setminus(X+n)|\ge\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you @bof. My problem when thinking about this comes from the following perspective. The sets $G$ and $G \cap (n,n+1)$ need not be equal. Both of these sets are measurable, and $|G| \geq |G \cap (n,n+1)|$. How come that $|G \setminus (X+n)| = |(G \cap (n,n+1))\setminus (X+n)|=\varepsilon$?

Comment: @RonW Where did I say that $|G\setminus(X+n)|=|G\cap(n,n+1)\setminus(X+n)|$??

Comment: Thank you for following up with my question. I think that you clearly say that $|[∩(,+1)] \setminus (+)|≥$ and $|G \setminus (X+n)| \geq \varepsilon$. While the latter is clear, how do we know the former?  (I am super-sorry for being so persistent on this stupid question, obviously there is something fundamental I don't get here).

Comment: @RonW Are you OK with Claim 3? The inequality $|[G\cap(n,n+1)]\setminus(X+n)|\ge\varepsilon$ in Claim 4 is obtained by substituting $G\cap(n,n+1)$ for the $G$ in Claim 3.