# Why $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} | (G \cap (n, n+1)) \setminus (X+n)| \geq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \varepsilon=\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

Let  $X \subset (0,1)$ be a non-measurable set. Define $A= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (X+n)$.  Let $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set such that $A \subseteq G$. Finally, let $|G \setminus (X+n)| \geq \varepsilon > 0$ for all $n$, where $|S|$ denotes the outer measure of some set $S$.

How can we show, that  $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} | (G \cap (n, n+1)) \setminus (X+n)| \geq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \varepsilon$?

I have a problem seeing this. I understand that $(X+n) \subset (n,n+1)$. Also, $(X+n) \subset A \subseteq G$. In order to show the weak inequality, we need to show that $| (G \cap (n, n+1)) \setminus (X+n)| \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But we only know that $| G \setminus X| = | G \setminus (X+n)| \geq \varepsilon$ (by translation invariance of the outer measure). How can we then show that $| (G \cap (n, n+1)) \setminus (X+n)| \geq \varepsilon$ (the very same $\varepsilon$) for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2):

For *every* set $H \supset X$, we know that $|H \setminus X | \geq \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon > 0$, which is shown in the post [There exists a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $|G \setminus A|= \infty$ for each open set containing $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834087/there-exists-a-set-a-subset-mathbbr-with-g-a-infty-for-each-open-set-co) Let $(X+n) \subset H$, where $(X+n) = \{x + n | x \in X\}$. By translation invariance, $|H \setminus X | = |H \setminus (X + n)|$. As $(X+n) \subset (G \cap (n,n+1))$, consider $H = (G \cap (n,n+1))$. Thus
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |(G \cap (n,n+1)) \setminus (X+n) | \geq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \varepsilon = \infty \,.
\end{equation}